# How to Print Only Strings Listed in A given Array list in Java

Tags: java

I'm a bit new to Java. I would like my scanner to be able to read only the strings in  my array list. This should work in such a way that when a user tries to type a name not declared inside the array list, it should display print out the message indicating that the city is not present on the list.

So far this is what I have done but I realised that it only prints the first string "Poznan" correctly but when I enter the names of other cities, it throws the error message that it isn't part of the list which is very false. It reads only the first string. What could be wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class New {
    public static  void main (String[]args) {

        String [] cities = {"Poznan", "Warsaw", "Gdansk", "Wroclaw", "Krakow", "Lodz", "Katowice"};
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("What is the name of your city in Poland? ");

        String name = scan.nextLine();

        for (String n:cities) {
            if (n.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                System.out.println("You are citizen of Poland from " +name);
                System.out.println("Thank your for visiting  " +name);
            }


            else {
                System.out.println("You are not from Poland!!!" );
                System.out.println("There is not city in Poland called" +name);
            }
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You break your loop on the first iteration, so none of the elements of your array are checked after the first.

Comment: The real answer here: step back. Take a piece of paper, and a pen. Then run your code "mentally". Write down what is in each variable, write down "what happens". Like: it takes the user input and compares it with the first city. Is it equal .. then ... else. And no matter what, there is a break after the if else. Hmm.

Comment: Also note, conceptually, this wont work, even when you (re)move the break. What you want to do instead: have a boolean marker like `boolean foundCity = false`. You iterate the array, and if an entry matches the user input, you toggle that boolean. Then **after** the loop you do `if (foundCity)` ONCE.

Comment: Don't print anything in the loop. The purpose of the loop is to determine if the city is in the list. Store your findings in a variable. After the loop print your findings based on the variable.